# Card overlay slide in only over image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a gallery section of cards using Bootstrap 4 and would like user to hover over each card to have an overlay slide / or fade in but only cover the image. As of now it slides on over the whole card.

I can't seem to get it to just fit the card. I know as of now I have the `width` and `height` set to 100% which covers the whole card but when I remove that the overlay is small and slides in over the gap between image and border. Any ideas?

HTML of one of the cards:

```
<div class="card mt-6">
  <div class="px-3">
    <div class="card-overlay">
      <h1 class="card-overlay-heading">Meet Brian!</h1>
      <script src="https://fast.wistia.com/embed/medias/.jsonp" async></script>
      <script src="https://fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js" async></script>
      <span class="wistia_embed wistia_async_ popover=true popoverContent=link" style="display:inline;position:relative">
                                        <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></a></span>
    </div>
    <img src="images/Lorraine.png" class="card-img" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h6 class="card-title mb-0 text-uppercase">Mark D</h6>
    <p class="card-text mb-3  text-green fw-bold">Web</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.card {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card:hover .card-overlay {
  left: 0;
}

.card-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  background-color: rgba(85, 211, 150, 0.6);
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  transition: left .7s;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to the *wrapper* of the image (now the `overlay` is *relative* to the `card` and that's why you have it over the whole card) - see demo below:

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.card > div { /* ADDED THIS */
  position: relative;
}

.card:hover .card-overlay {
  left: 0;
}

.card-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  background-color: rgba(85, 211, 150, 0.6);
  color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  transition: left .7s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="card mt-6" style="width:300px">
    <div class="px-3">
      <div class="card-overlay">
        <h1 class="card-overlay-heading">Meet Brian!</h1>
        <span class="wistia_embed wistia_async_ popover=true popoverContent=link" style="display:inline;position:relative">
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-play"></i></a></span>
      </div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" class="card-img" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h6 class="card-title mb-0 text-uppercase">Mark D</h6>
      <p class="card-text mb-3  text-green fw-bold">Web</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```